# Empty set is returned with no errors

Tags: java, set, bufferedreader

I have to read through a file, take the lines and add them to a custom service class, then add that service class to a timeTable. The timeTable returned however is empty.

- Assume the format of the file is correct

This is the file:

```
3
v1
1 v2 v3
2 v4
3

v2
1 
2 v1 v4
3
```

Code:

```
while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {

    if (firstLine){
        //Set session
        numberOfSessions = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
        firstLine = false;

    } else if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        correctSession = 0;     
    } else if(correctSession < numberOfSessions + 1) {
        //Split the current line
        String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");

        //Check if it is the "Name" line
        if (correctSession == 0) {
            sourceName = line.trim(); 
            //Increase correct session
            correctSession++;
        } else { 
            //Add it to timetable as a service
            for (int i = 1;i < lineSplit.size();i++) {
                //Venue(String)
                Venue source = new Venue(sourceName);
                Venue destination = new Venue(splitLine[i]);

                //Service(venue, venue, int)
                Service service = new Service(source,destination,Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]));

                timeTable.addService(service); /* This does not seem to be working*/
            }
            //Increase correct session
            correctSession++;
        }
    }           
}
//Close the reader
buffReader.close();
```

OutCome:

```
Actual: []
Expected: [Departs v1 after session 1 for v3, Departs v1 after session 2 for v4, Departs v1 after session 1 for v2, Departs v2 after session 2 for v4, Departs v2 after session 2 for v1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you appear to be iterating the wrong thing (your variable names are very similar). But this,

```
for (int i = 1;i < lineSplit.size();i++) {
```

should be (because arrays start at `0`) something like

```
for (int i = 0;i < splitLine.length;i++) {
```

Or, using [The `For-Each` Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
for (String destinationName : splitLine) {
    //Venue(String)
    Venue source = new Venue(sourceName);
    // Venue destination = new Venue(splitLine[i]);
    Venue destination = new Venue(destinationName);
```

Comment: The reason I am using i = 1 is because I don;t want to read the first element, since that is a number and I just want the names v1 or v2.